# EF Core parallel write to DB via Task

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core, task

There is a file that is read in portions, each portion is returned through **yield return**, then the **Task** responsible for writing the read lines to the database should be launched using **EF Core**. The problem is that it is impossible to run several operations at once on one context.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
   foreach (var portion in reader.ReadPortions(file, 1000))
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await saver.SaveWithMerge(portion)));

   Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: It can't. EF is explicitly single-threaded, so one context does one operation at a time on one thread. If you want to use multiple contexts then each one can only do one operation at a time on one thread.

Answer (score 4):

> is impossible to run several operations at once on one context.

This is correct. Your options are:

1. Perform all the changes and then do a single `SaveChangesAsync`.
2. Use multiple EF contexts, one for each concurrent update.
3. Batch the changes and call `SaveChangesAsync` in-between each batch.